# How to make a CTRunRef object? (iPhone SDK 4)

Tags: ios4, core-text

There is several CTLineCreate* functions, but I can't find a function which make CTRunRef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CTRun` values are created by Core Text when needed (specifically, they're created by `CTTypesetter`/`CTLine` and supplied by `CTLineGetGlyphRuns()`.)

If you're trying to draw glyph runs with `CTRunDraw()`, use `CTTypesetter` to set up your text first. If you need `CTRun` values for some other purpose... what is it? :)

Comment: I just tried to draw CTRun instead of CTLine. Because it seemed to be lighter. Thank you!